# STM32F100 PWM with SPL setup

Tags: stm32, stm32f1

I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong with my PWM setup on PC6 with my STM32F100 MCU, TIM3 Channel 1.

It is an old project with only one pin left that I am trying to expand a little bit.

My current setup is like this :
#EDITED the TIM_SetCompare3(SERVO_TIM, 5000); to 50 as suggested below but no joy.

```
void SERVO_Init(void) 
{

    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseStructure ;
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef TIM_OCInitStructure;

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APBxPeriph_SERVO_PWM_TIM, ENABLE);
    
    /* configure Projector fan PWM timer */
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 65535;    /* 24 MHz divided by this gives pwm input clock */
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 100-1; /* 100 0..99     */
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(SERVO_TIM, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 50;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;

    TIM_OC1Init(SERVO_TIM, &TIM_OCInitStructure);
    
    /* turning on PROJ_FAN_TIM PWM output */
    TIM_Cmd(SERVO_TIM, ENABLE);
    TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(SERVO_TIM, ENABLE);
```

I know I need to setup this as an alternat function pinout but I can seem to get anything oput of the pin.
In my main loop I have

```
TIM_SetCompare1(SERVO_TIM, 50);
}
```

Since I can not change the current code to HAL I am stuck with SPL sadly.

I have also found the following online but get plenty errors with this :

```
TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef  TIM_TimeBaseStructure;
TIM_OCInitTypeDef  TIM_OCInitStructure;
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

/* GPIOA, GPIOB and GPIOE Clocks enable */
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd( RCC_APBxPeriph_SERVO_PWM_TIM, ENABLE);

// Set to Alt function
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = SERVO_PWM_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  GPIO_InitStructure.OutputType = GPIO_OUTPUT_PUSHPULL;
  GPIO_Init(SERVO_PWM_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

  GPIO_AF_EnableRemap_TIM3();

// setup timer scales
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 65535;    /* 24 MHz divided by this gives pwm input clock */
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 100-1; /* 100 0..99     */
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(SERVO_TIM, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 5000;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;

// enable settings
TIM_OC1Init(SERVO_TIM, &TIM_OCInitStructure);

/* turning on SERVO PWM output */
TIM_Cmd(SERVO_TIM, ENABLE);
TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(SERVO_TIM, ENABLE);
```

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while a colleague found an old snippet of code that he had working years ago.
Long and short of it is that I had the Remap function in the wrong place and I had a PWM on TIM3 channel 3 ( PB0 ) this one does not play nicely with TIM3 channel 1 on PC6 so I had to get rid of the PWM on PB0, lucky my project could work with that and I'll just bit bang the signal I need later.

Here is the setup I ended up using for anyone who needs help with this, it is in unsupported Standard Peripheral libraries so can be ifficult to get help.
Also another problem I had was I thought I could use PC4 with TIM12 but my package was not a high density device and so this was not supported.

```
#define SERVO_PWM_GPIO_Port GPIOC
#define SERVO_PWM_Pin       GPIO_Pin_6
#define SERVO_TIM TIM3
#define RCC_APBxPeriph_SERVO_ENABLE_TIM     RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3


void SERVO_Init(void) {

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = (SERVO_PWM_Pin);
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_10MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM_TimeBaseStructure ;
    TIM_OCInitTypeDef TIM_OCInitStructure;

    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APBxPeriph_SERVO_ENABLE_TIM, ENABLE);

    /* configure UV LED PWM timer */
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 24-1;    /* 24 MHz divided by this gives pwm input clock */
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period = 10000-1; /* 10000 0..9999     */
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 1;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(SERVO_TIM, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 0;
    TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;

    TIM_OC1Init(SERVO_TIM, &TIM_OCInitStructure); /* uv led pwm */

    /* turning on UV_LED_TIM PWM output */
    TIM_Cmd(SERVO_TIM, ENABLE);
    TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(SERVO_TIM, ENABLE);

// Turn off the PWR to the SERVO
GPIO_SetBits(SERVO_ENABLE_GPIO_Port, SERVO_ENABLE_Pin);
// GPIO_SetBits(SERVO_PWM_GPIO_Port, SERVO_PWM_Pin);

GPIO_PinRemapConfig(GPIO_FullRemap_TIM3, ENABLE);

}
```

This final line  Remapping the TIM3 was important and one that I did not have in the correct place before this.

The PWM signal is set with :

```
TIM_SetCompare1(SERVO_TIM, valueWanted); // between 9999 and 0 in this setup.
```

All the comments and answers below did still help, thanks for all those that made the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Timer period is 100, yet OC pulse is set to 5000. Timer counter never reaches this value.

Call to `TIM_SetCompare3(SERVO_TIM, 5000);` will set pulse length on SERVO_TIM's channel 3. You've already set pulse length on channel 1 with `TIM_OC1Init`.

If you don't like SPL, then revert to the direct register programming. This way you'll get better understanding of the mcu.

Comment: Hi, as soon as I posted this I saw that mistake, but I am still getting no joy after correcting it, if you have any other hints I would love to hear them.

Comment: Sadly I can not change the code as the time line I have does not give me the time to port anything.

Comment: Sorry ment to inlucde the mismatch in channles as well, I have edited the question.

Comment: @Spider999 something might be missing in other parts of the code, like clocking. AFIO clocking must be enabled (not shown), GPIO clocking must be enabled (now shown, however the comment states otherwise). It's also not clear which code snippet you are working with, first has no GPIO confg and no remap.

Comment: I am using the first code snippet, the second one I think has wrong references for my libraries, sorry for the inconsitencies, it has reached the point where I am grabbing at straws, I try to only post here as a last resort.
My problem stems from the lack of SPL guides or anything explaining it on the internet. I will look up GPIO and AFIO clocking but since I have many other IO and PWM's working on this I have my doubts it could be that, thanks again for the pointers.